# Unmet dependencies problem when installing vlc on Ubuntu22.04: libva-wayland2 : Depends: libva2

Tags: apt, vlc, 22.04

When I tried to install vlc on 22.04, I got the following error message:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libva-wayland2 : Depends: libva2 (< 2.13.0.1) but 2.14.0-1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Usually apt would install the required lib automatically, but this one doesn't.

Here is the `sudo apt update` message:

```
Ign:5 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/videolan/stable-daily/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Err:6 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/videolan/stable-daily/ubuntu jammy Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.52 443]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/videolan/stable-daily/ubuntu jammy Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

In addition, I tried install it with `sudo snap install vlc`, the installation is only partially successful. It can only open files from limited folder path. Several disks mounted cannot be open, and only the files in those original basic Linux folders and home folder can be open. I guess this is related with this `libva` problem.

Comment: Run `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade` first, then try to install vlc again.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)  Check here first. If you need additional help, add the output of `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade` to your question. Provide the whole undoctored output of commands- not just the parts you believe are important. Also include the command you are using.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa)